# Complex Analysis analytic function 1$f(z)=z$

Tags: complex-analysis

if$\text{ } f:D(0,1)\longrightarrow D(0,1)$

is  analytic such that there exists

$a,b\in D(0,1)$ and $\text{ }$$f(a)=a$ , $f(b)=b$

prove that $f(z)=z$      $\forall$ $z\in D(0,1)$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Use the [Schwarz lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma#Statement). ${}$